# Get a warning when I overwrite a function in Julia?

Tags: julia

Julia by default imports many names into scope. Is there a way to get a warning when I inadvertently overwrite one of them?

Comment: This has already been changed in the development version (which will become julia-0.5)---now you get a warning.

Comment: Yes, and while trying to get rid of some of the warnings in packages I've been using on Julia v0.5, I've managed to find and fix a number of bugs (the bugs were in v0.3 & v0.4, but nobody noticed until now), so this is a very welcome change in the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of modules and Base functions, Julia already does warn you if you overwrite a name. See the below examples that work on v`0.4.5`:

**MODULES:**

In modA.jl:

```
module modA

export test

function test()
    println("modA")
end
end
```

In modB.jl:

```
module modB

export test

function test()
    println("modB")
end
end
```

In REPL:

```
julia> using modA
julia> using modB
WARNING: Using modB.test in module Main conflicts with an existing identifier
julia> test()
"modA"
```

**BASE FUNCTIONS**:

In REPL:

```
julia> function +(x::Float64, y::Float64)
    println("my addition")
end

julia> WARNING: module Main should explicitly import + from Base
WARNING: Method definition +(Float64, Float64) in module Base at float.jl:208 
overwritten in module Main at none:2.
```

As far as I am aware, this does not work with user defined functions; see below:

```
julia> function test(x::Float64, y::Float64)
    println("First Definition")
end

julia> test(1.0, 2.0)
First Definition

julia> function test(x::Float64, y::Float64)
    println("Second Definition")
end

julia> test(1.0, 2.0)
Second Definition
```

Did you have a different context in mind for imported names?

Comment: If I do, for example, `readdlm(x) = x^2` in the REPL, it doesn't give any warning (v0.4.2), in spite of the fact that this overwrites `readdlm`.

Comment: This throws an error in v0.4.5 `ERROR: error in method definition: function DataFmt.readdlm must be explicitly imported to be extended`. This functionality may have been/added improved since 0.4.2.

Comment: I just have to wait until Julia 0.4.5 gets on the Ubuntu ppa.

Comment: I've always found it quite easy to compile Julia from source on Ubuntu and Fedora. Might be worth giving is a shot if this is a big issue for you.

Comment: @becko I don't think that is going to happen. Try installing a precompiled generic binary from the official site.

Comment: @colinfang Why not? The PPA is recommended on the official site (http://julialang.org/downloads/platform.html).

Comment: @becko That page is old. See http://julialang.org/downloads/ (Though it doesn't say PPA is going to be removed. I remember it was mentioned  in a thread somewhere.)